# What is the order of the differential equation $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Firstly, I know that both $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial y^2}=0$ are second order differntial equation but what is the order of $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=0$?

Secondly, what is the degree of the differential equations $\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)^7+\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)^5+\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}\right)^3=0$ and $\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)^7+\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\right)^3=0$.

Comment: All of the PDE mentioned are second order. The order of a PDE is the highest order derivative in the PDE